# Service weblogic.server.ServerLifeCycle Service was started at level 9 but it has a run level of 10

Tags: weblogic12c

I have little knowledge in WebLogic and the demand arose to upload the application on a new server.

When I upload the WebLogic12c adminServer (startAdminServer.sh), the following error occurs:

```
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Service weblogic.server.ServerLifeCycleService was started at level 9 but it has a run level of 10.  The full descriptor is SystemDescriptor(
        implementation=weblogic.server.ServerLifeCycleService
        name=ServerLifeCycleService
        contracts={weblogic.server.ServerLifeCycleService,weblogic.server.ServerService}
        scope=org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevel
        qualifiers={javax.inject.Named}
        descriptorType=CLASS
        descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
        metadata=runLevelValue={10}
        rank=0
        loader=HK2LoaderImpl(weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@1623b78d finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@4afb17c1 annotation: )
        proxiable=null
        proxyForSameScope=null
        analysisName=null
        id=158
        locatorId=0
        identityHashCode=1248382004
        reified=true)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.validate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:446)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:299)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:777)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Can you help me?

Comment: It can be w known issue described in Oracle's note "Integrated Weblogic Server Fails To Start After Applying WebLogic Server Patches (Doc ID 2846757.1)"
Can you provide more info about the exact version of WebLogic you are using and your path level ?

Comment: Thanks @Emanuel, the information was very useful.
The version of Weblogic consulted in the registry.xml file is 12.2.1.3.0
I don't know how to check the path level. Could you tell me how?

I forwarded the link (Doc ID 2846757.1) to the WebLogic configuration team. If there is a solution, return here.
Sorry for the bad English.